# Fetch data using mysql left join using where clause on both table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `custom_leads_fields` and `custom_leads_fields_option`. The `primary key` of `custom_leads_fields` is saved in `custom_leads_fields_option` table as `c_id`.

I need to fetch all the records from `custom_leads_fields` table where `status = 1` and then I also needs matching records from `custom_leads_fields_option` where `status = 1`

```
custom_leads_fields table
c_id | user_id | label | status | 
1    | 591     |   A   |   1    |
2    | 591     |   B   |   1    |
3    | 591     |   C   |   0    |

custom_leads_fields_option table
id | c_id                   | option | status 
1  |    2                   |   yes  |   1
2  |    2                   |   no   |   1
3  |    2                   |   may  |   0
4  |    3                   |   yy   |   1
5  |    3                   |   zz   |   1
```

Output required:

```
c_id   |  label  |   option
1      |    A    |     
2      |    B    |     yes
2      |    B    |     no
```

It should `return records` from `first table if status = 1` even if `records are not available in second table`, but if `records are available` in `second table` then `only those records should be fetched` whose `status = 1`.

I have written a query but it does not return label 'A' because matching records are not available in other table.

```
SELECT 
`custom_leads_fields`.`c_id` AS `field_id`, 
`custom_leads_fields_option`.`id` AS `option_id`, 
`custom_leads_fields`.`label`, 
`custom_leads_fields_option`.`option` 
FROM 
`custom_leads_fields` 
LEFT JOIN 
`custom_leads_fields_option` 
ON custom_leads_fields.id = custom_leads_fields_option.custom_leads_field_id 
WHERE 
(`custom_leads_fields`.`user_id`=591) 
AND (`custom_leads_fields`.`status`=1) 
AND (`custom_leads_fields_option`.`status`= 1)
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: it should also return lable A even if matching records are not available in other table

Comment: Put your where in join condition more like `custom_leads_fields.id = custom_leads_fields_option.custom_leads_field_id and custom_leads_fields.status = 1 and custom_leads_fields_option.status = 1`

Comment: on the join criteria can you change the query to map to the correct names of the id columns you've used in the sample tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is left join and the label A doesn't have any relationship with `custom_leads_fields_option` table. So you can't use `custom_leads_fields_option.status = 1`. You can try this

```
select clf.*, clfo.*
from custom_leads_fields clf
left join custom_leads_fields_option clfo
on clf.id = clfo.c_id
where clf.status = 1
and (clfo.status = 1 or clfo.status is null);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d744/5/0)

Comment: This solution is much more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

you need to move status condition to join condition , this will give your desired output. All the records from left table and matched record (with status =1 condition) from right table

```
SELECT 
`custom_leads_fields`.`c_id` AS `field_id`, 
`custom_leads_fields_option`.`id` AS `option_id`, 
`custom_leads_fields`.`label`, 
`custom_leads_fields_option`.`option` 
FROM 
`custom_leads_fields` 
LEFT JOIN 
`custom_leads_fields_option` 
ON custom_leads_fields.id = custom_leads_fields_option.custom_leads_field_id 
AND (`custom_leads_fields_option`.`status`= 1) // changed line
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE 
(`custom_leads_fields`.`user_id`=591) 
AND (`custom_leads_fields`.`status`=1)
```